# handling submit exception in React Redux forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm stuck at how properly to handle exceptions on submitting in redux forms.
On error I would like to show a toast message.

**LogIn.js:**

```
class LogIn extends PureComponent {
  onSubmit = (values) => {
    const { login } = this.props;
    try {
      login(fromJS(values));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

// Login function is mapped through connect

```
const mapDispatchToActions = {
  login: userActions.login,
};

const withRedux = reduxForm({
  form: 'log_in_form',
});

export default withRouter(connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToActions,
)(withRedux(LogIn)));
```

**user.Actions.js**

Here I must show UI notification when an exception occurs.
For this, I throw SubmissionError which is caught in the code above but instead
it throws an error:

> user.Actions.js:61 Uncaught (in promise) SubmissionError {errors: {…},
> message: "Submit Validation Failed

Please, what is the proper way to implement this?
I believe that showing UI messages from actions is a bad design.
I'd like to intercept an exception in the form and show UI message.

```
function login(values) {
  const request = user => ({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user });
  const newPasswordRequired = user => ({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_PASSWORD_RESET_FORWARD_REQUEST, user });
  const success = user => ({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user });
  const failure = error => ({ type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error });

  const { name, password } = values.toJS();

  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(request({ name }));

    try {
      const user = await userService.login(name, password);

      if (user.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
        dispatch(newPasswordRequired(user));
        history.push('/reset');
      } else {
        dispatch(success(user));
        history.push('/demo');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(failure(error));
      dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
      throw new SubmissionError(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason in that exception was

```
  onSubmit = (values) => {
    const { login } = this.props;
    try {
      login(fromJS(values));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Should have been made async